# Density Plot con R. Por qué los valores en el eje vertical Y son mayores de 1? Hay algo mal en mi código?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, visualización-de-datos

[image: Density Plot con R]

Density Plot con R. Por qué los valores en el eje vertical Y son mayores de 1? Hay algo mal en mi código?

Supongo que como los valores de probabilidad no pueden ser mayores a 1, algo debería estar mal. Pero, no estoy seguro. Pueden revisar el código y aclararme mi duda?

```
library(datasets)
str(iris)

library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_classic())

 # Plot
 g <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length,  fill=Species))
 myDensityPlotWithGGplot <- g + geom_density() + 
 labs(title="Density plot", 
   subtitle="Petal Length by Species",
   caption="Source: Iris Set",
   x="Petal Length",
   fill="Species")

 myDensityPlotWithGGplot

 library(plotly)

 myDensityPlotWithPLOTLY <- ggplotly(myDensityPlotWithGGplot)

 myDensityPlotWithPLOTLY
```

Comment: No veo nada mal, sí es posible que el valor de la función supere la unidad, lo que no es posible es con la integral.
![gaussian](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma&space;\sqrt{2\pi&space;}}e^{-\frac{(x-u)^{2}}{2\sigma&space;^{2}}})
Cuando la desviación es cercana a 0 en la funcion gaussiana el valor tiende a infinito.

Comment: @AlfredoMaussa Fantástico comentario! Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la función de densidad, la probabilidad no viene determinada por el valor del eje Y, sino por el área bajo la curva. Si haces la integral de la curva que representa a la especie Iris setosa no será mayor a 1 (como comenta @Alfredo Maussa). Si el valor de esta integral fuera mayor a 1, entonces sí que estaría mal.

Si lo que quieres es que el máximo del eje Y sea 1, puedes hacerlo con la opción `scaled`:

```
ggplot(iris) +
  geom_density(aes(x=Petal.Length,  fill=Species, ..scaled..)) + 
  labs(title="Scaled Density plot", 
       subtitle="Petal Length by Species",
       caption="Source: Iris Set",
       x="Petal Length",
       fill="Species")
```

Comment: Brillante respuesta! Gracias!